# Error create new entity with navigation property Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a problem with insert procedure in my application in ASP .NET MVC. I describe my environment and after I will explain my problem.

I have 2 model classes: Projects and Task

**PROJECT**

```
[Table("Project")]
public class Project
{
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ProjectID { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name project required")]
    [StringLength(300, MinimumLength = 1)]
    [DisplayName("Name of Project")]
    public string NameProject { get; set; }

    //Other properties...

    public Project()
    {
        Tasks = new HashSet<Task>();
    }
    public virtual ICollection<Task> Tasks { get; set; }

}
```

**TASK**

```
[Table("Task")]
public class Task
{
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int TaskID { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Task Name required")]
    [StringLength(300, MinimumLength = 1)]
    public string TaskName { get; set; }


    public virtual Project Project { get; set; }

}
```

And this is **TASKMANAGER** where I insert code to manage dbContext. This is the *createNewTask function*.

```
public void createTask(Task task,int projectID)
{
    Project pr = db.Project.Find(projectID);        
    task.Project = pr;
    db.Task.Add(task);
    db.SaveChanges();

}
```

And here is a snapshot from my **database**:

[Database Snapshot](http://sdrv.ms/16jn3LZ)

**And the problem is:**

When I try insert new task, the system give me an error: * Can not add a null value to the column 'Project_ProjectID' for entity 'Task' *.

But, I don't understand this!! When I debug the application, I can see that in the insert function, the variable 'int projectID' is correct, and the line 'Project pr = db.Project.Find(projectID)' works well, but when it's arrive to '**SaveChanges()**'... it's crashed.

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the following property to your Task entity:
- public virtual int ProjectId.

Finally, I suggest to add the entities like this:
- Project.Task.Add(yourCurrentTask).

Comment: Hi! Thanks for you help, but this not work. I take note about you suggest to add the task in list of task from project. But other thing, not work because 'ProjectId' isn't a column that the exception says me.

Comment: Ok, now I understand. I recommend this post to understand relationships in CodeFirst http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh134698.aspx . My problem was that I needed add fluent api configuration in modelBuilder. Thanks a lot khnumdev